# How to get specific row to insert controls

Tags: c#, tablelayoutpanel

I am trying to insert a row in a c# tableLayoutPanel at a determined location.

I need to check for the first row that does not contain a checkmark in one of the labels and set that as the row to insert the control.

Even though I think I set the insertRow in the for loop, when it gets to the point of inserting the row, the insertRow value is 0.  It seems that when the for loop is exited, the insertRow value reverts back to 0. If I don't initialize the insertRow with "= 0" then when I get an error message about using an unassigned variable. I would really appreciate any help.

```
        int insertRow = 0;
        int rowCount = tableLayoutPanel2.RowCount;

        //Get first row without member listed
        for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount - 1; i++)
        {
            if (tableLayoutPanel2.GetControlFromPosition(1, i).Text != "✔")
            {
                insertRow = i;
            }
        }
        //Add Row to table
        tableLayoutPanel2.RowCount++;
        tableLayoutPanel2.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 29));
        //Insert Row
        tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = Name.Text, TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter, Anchor = AnchorStyles.None, AutoSize = false }, 0, insertRow);
```

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code? Why are you starting at the second row? Row and column indices are zero-based. You are also only looking at the second column.

Comment: when I set the break point, that's how I know that the value for insertRow is not kept. It increments during the for loop, but once the for loop completes, it's back to zero.

Comment: I'm starting at the second row since the first is just column headers. (I know the value won't be contained there.)  The checkmark will only be in the second column.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all I needed was to "break" out of the loop to keep the insertRow variable set.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount - 1; i++)
        {
            if (tableLayoutPanel2.GetControlFromPosition(1, i).Text != "✔")
            {
                insertRow = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        //Add Row to table
        tableLayoutPanel2.RowCount++;
        tableLayoutPanel2.RowStyles.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.RowStyle(System.Windows.Forms.SizeType.Absolute, 29));
        //Insert member
        tableLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(new Label() { Text = Name.Text, TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter, Anchor = AnchorStyles.None, AutoSize = false }, 0, insertRow);
```